# Sed - stop multi-part command if pattern doesn't match?

Tags: sed

All, I'm trying to run a `sed` command to strip out card numbers from certain files.  I was trying to do this in a one-liner and I thought all was going well - but I realized that if my first substitute didn't match the pattern it continued into the next commands.  Is there a way to get it to exit if there is no match?

We have 16-22 length card numbers on our system, so I wrote this with a variable length in mind.  My specifications were to preserve the first 6 and last 4 of any 16+ digit number, and axe (asterisk) out anything in the middle.

```
sed 'h;s/[0-9]\{6\}\([0-9]\{5\}\)\([0-9]*\)[0-9]\{4\}/\1\2/;s/./*/g;x;s/\([0-9]\{6\}\)[0-9]*\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1\2/;G;s/\n//;s/\([0-9]\{6\}\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\1\3\2/'
```

The problem lies in the fact that if this part of the command:

```
s/[0-9]\{6\}\([0-9]\{5\}\)\([0-9]*\)[0-9]\{4\}/\1\2/
```

Finds nothing, the pattern space remains the input.  It continues into the next command which then replaces everything with asterisks.  What I end up with is the input followed by an equal number of asterisks (if it does not match the "card number qualifications" in my first substitute).  It works perfectly if it *is* what is deemed a possible card number.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's a card number? Credit card number?

Comment: I find `/pattern/{s//replacement/;....}` or the negative `/pattern/!{...}` can be quite useful when needing an `if/unless` idiom in sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I realized that if my first substitute didn't match the pattern it
>   continued into the next commands. Is there a way to get it to exit if
>   there is no match?

You can use branch commands. I added and commented them in place:

```
sed '
    h;
    s/[0-9]\{6\}\([0-9]\{5\}\)\([0-9]*\)[0-9]\{4\}/\1\2/;

    ## If last substitution command succeeds, go to label "a".
    t a
    ## Begin next cycle (previous substitution command didn't succeed).
    b
    ## Label "a".
    :a

    s/./*/g;
    x;
    s/\([0-9]\{6\}\)[0-9]*\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1\2/;
    G;
    s/\n//;
    s/\([0-9]\{6\}\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\1\3\2/
'
```

---

**UPDATE** due to comments.

So you want to transform

```
texttexttext111111222223333texttexttext
```

in

```
texttexttext111111*****3333texttexttext
```

Try:

```
echo "texttexttext111111222223333texttexttext" | 
sed -e '
    ## Add newlines characters between the characters to substitute with "*".
    s/\([0-9]\{6\}\)\([0-9]\{5\}\)\([0-9]*\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1\n\2\3\n\4/;
    ## Label "a".
    :a; 
    ## Substitute first not-asterisk character between newlines with "*".
    s/\(\n\**\)[^\n]\(.*\n\)/\1*\2/; 
    ## If character before second newline is not an asterisk, repeat
    ## the substitution from label "a".
    /^.*\*\n/! ta; 
    ## Remove artificial newlines.
    s/\n//g
    ## Implicit print.
'
```

Output:

```
texttexttext111111*****3333texttexttext
```

Comment: +1, Bravo! I really think the desire for a sed 1-liner is so often the wrong approach ;-).

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well. I did find a new problem, not in the OP, though. Say I have a line item that is like such: texttexttext11111222223333texttexttext - The goal of this script would be to return that exact line with only the 2's replaced with *'s.  On my first substitute command I'm running into a problem because it is doing exactly what it says, substituting, but only my numeric portion (while still including the text outside of the number) in my returned value for asterisk'ing.  Is there a way the s command can return only the substituted pattern and omit the rest of the line?

Comment: @user1695263: I don't fully understand you. Do you want to substitute all `2` with `*` and remove all other characters? Then your previous example would yield in `*****`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Birei, I want to remove it for the remainder of the commands.  The output I'm after would be texttexttext111111******3333texttexttext.  If you run the commands as you have them above you will not get that, rather you'd get something like texttexttext111111texttexttext******************************3333.  The reason for this is the second s command should only be getting the middle segment of numbers as input, but rather its getting everything before the number, the middle segment of the number, and everything after the number.

Comment: I had to change a few things - but I get "sed: a is not a defined label.".  Are we using different versions of sed?  It appears it doesn't like it unless I put the label after where I invoke it - which wouldn't let me loop.

Comment: @user1695263: How are you running that command? As a one-liner?

Comment: I was trying to run it out of a file, so I took your sed commands and placed them in a file and then was invoking with "sed -f scriptfile "texttexttext....".  I found on the web the fact that some versions of sed liked the label on its own and I was able to get it to run like this:echo "texttexttext1111112222223333texttexttext" | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{6\}\)\([0-9]\{5\}\)\([0-9]*\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1\n\2\3\n\4/' | sed -e ':a' -e 's/\(\n\**\)[^\n]\(.*\n\)/\1*\2/;s/^.*\*\n/!/;t a' | sed -e 's/\n//g'.

Comment: @user1695263: Ok. Then, you got it :-). Perhaps you can rid of the pipes with `echo ... | sed -e 'command1' -e ':a' -e 'command2; command3; ...'`, but I can't test it because my version is `GNU sed versión 4.2.1` and labels work fine in the same instruction.

Answer (score 1):

From `man sed`:

```
t label
      If  a  s///  has  done  a successful substitution since the last
      input line was read and since the last  t  or  T  command,  then
      branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.

T label
      If  no  s///  has  done a successful substitution since the last
      input line was read and since the last  t  or  T  command,  then
      branch  to  label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.
      This is a GNU extension.
```

So I think you can just add `T;` after your first `s` command.