# How to stop a sed script if finding two start patterns before an end pattern?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, svn, sed

I need to find all revisions in a subversion dump that have changes to pom.xml.

I'm using [svndumptool](https://github.com/jwiegley/svndumptool) to successfully print the revisions, and then sed to filter those findings.

I'm able to match the revision number as the start, but I need to be able to throw this away if I find a second matching start before I find a stop.

Here is the command I’m using:

```
    svnDumpTool=~/path/to/svndumptool.py
    target=specificSvn.dump

    # use svndumptool to read the svnlog from target to stdin | 
    # sed then matches start -r[0-9], such as -r103, ends on pom.xml
    # then redirects stdout > to a log file for this target

    $svnDumpTool log $target -v | sed -n '/r[0-9]/,/pom.xml/p' > $target.log
```

Considering a log of something like this:

```
    -r0 | ... | ...
    Changed paths:
    none; initialization of the repo; not my match
    -r1 | ... | ...
    Changed paths:
    ... not my matches here
    --------
    -r2 | ... | ...
    Changed paths:
    ... nor here
    --------
    -r3 | ... | ...
    Changed paths:
    pom.xml
    --------
    -r4 | ... | ...
    Changed paths:
    pom.xml
    --------
    -r5 | ... | ...
    Changed paths:
    ... changes may or may not be here
    --------
```

Here are the results.

1. On the first pass, I get more than I want:

   - I'll get a match on start of -r0,
   - A match on end of pom.xml from -r3,
   - Which prints all from start to stop, including -r0, -r1 & -r2:

     ```
     -r0 | ... | ...
     Changed paths:
     none; initialization of the repo; not my match
     -r1 | ... | ...
     Changed paths:
     ... not my matches here
     --------
     -r2 | ... | ...
     Changed paths:
     ... nor here
     --------
     -r3 | ... | ...
     Changed paths:
     pom.xml
     ```
2. On the second pass, I get exactly what I want:

   - I'll get a match on start of -r4,
   - A match on end of pom.xml from -r4:

     ```
     -r4 | ... | ...
     Changed paths:
     pom.xml
     ```

So, what I think I need to do is:

1. If I find a start,
2. And I find another expression matching start before finding an expression matching end,
3. Then throw away the first start; otherwise print.

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570701/sed-stop-multi-part-command-if-pattern-doesnt-match) might have my answer, but any attempt I have tried has failed.

*EDIT: Auto-correct got me, and I incorrectly listed the output as "Pom.xml" when it should be "pom.xml".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/-r[0-9]/{h;d};H;/Pom.xml/!d;x' file
```

This stores lines beginning with `-r[0-9]` and those thereafter in the hold space, overwriting those already in the HS with newer ones until a line containing `Pom.xml` when it prints all such lines out.

Comment: This worked well; it does what I was thinking and gave a similar output to the awk script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) for this kind of thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $svnDumpTool = '~/path/to/svndumptool.py';
my $target      = 'specificSvn.dump';

my @rev = split /----*/, `$svnDumpTool log $target -v`;
foreach (@rev) {
  print if m/-r\d+[\s\S]*?Pom\.xml/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed is the wrong tool here. You *can* do it (sed is Turing-complete), but it's going to be unreadable.

Awk is likely to work a lot better. I'm not familiar with `svndumptool`; assuming it puts the separator `--------` between revisions, you can use that as the record separator. GNU awk allows regular expressions as the record separator.

```
awk -v RS='--------\n' -v ORS='--------\n' '
  /^pom\.xml$/ { print }
'
```

Comment: Thanks a coworker recommended awk as well; the script was a lot easier to read than `sed` because it was just basic regex with a couple awk commands.

Comment: Also I like the splitting on dashes separator, clever!